# Быстрое создание div с классом

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, jsx, hotkeys

Начала учить react, столкнулась с тем что в JSX не могу быстро создавать классы для кнопок и дивов как в обычном css и html при верстке, т.е. например div.className + tab не работает - только добавляет табуляцию. В курсах и видео роликах же люди спокойно используют какой-то вариант горячих клавиш. Поиск в гугле в течении 20 минут результатов не дал, но вычитала много для себя интересного - например про снипеты) В живую спросить не у кого, пожалуйста подскажите как решить эту проблему.

Редактор - vs code.

Comment: вы бы хоть программу упомянули, в которой клавишу tab нажимаете.

Comment: Извините, vs code

Comment: в vscode emmet работает по умолчанию (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet) в каком файле была попытка это использовать?\

Comment: app.js post.jsx

Comment: в файлах `jsx` должно работать, в файле `.js` - не должно

Comment: после установки расширения Emmet JSS (Mithril Emmet был установлен по умолчанию) - начал работать в jsx - но в app.js все также добавляет только табуляцию вместо создания класса

Comment: <div className="App">
      <PostLists posts={posts}/>
</div>
Значит все подобные конструкции прописываются в ручную и коротких путей нет?

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответы, до меня наконец-то дошла разница.